# can we assign objectdatasource control to a dataset?

Tags: c#, dataset, datasource

I have two questions:

1. Can we assign objectdatasource control to a dataset?
2. Can we return two or more tables using object data source control to gridview or detailsview.

My main focus is I have to store the object data source in the dataset otherwise my application will need to be changed by a lot.

Comment: how ? can you give me an example for that

Comment: your basically asking how to bind a dataset?

Answer (score 0):

1 Yes you can assign objectdatasource to a DataSet

```
private DataSet GetDataSet(ObjectDataSource ods)
{
var ds = new DataSet();
var dv = (DataView)ods.Select();
if (dv != null && dv.Count > 0)
{
var dt = dv.ToTable();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
}
return ds;
}
```

2 yes you can return lot of tables, but when you bind you specify your index table.

```
GridView1.DataSource = YourDataSet.Tables[0];
GridView2.DataSource = YourDataSet.Tables[2];
```

Comment: i didn't understood your logic but my question is how to store a objectdatasource controls data into a dataset

Answer (score 0):

An 'ObjectDataSource' has no data.
He simply returns the result of a method, this method should return an IEnumerable. The IEnumerable can be of POCO's, String's, Int32's, etc..

> how to store a objectdatasource controls data into a dataset

It would be possible if you return a "System.Data.DataTable" and then, **yes**, in this case you could store it in a "System.Data.DataSet". But for me, it makes little sense.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Creating and configuring the ObjectDataSource component:
    var objectDataSource = new Telerik.Reporting.ObjectDataSource();
    objectDataSource.DataSource = GetAllData(); // GetData returns a DataSet with three tables
    objectDataSource.DataMember = "Product"; /// Indicating the exact table to bind to. If the DataMember is not specified the first data table will be used.
    objectDataSource.CalculatedFields.Add(new Telerik.Reporting.CalculatedField("FullName", typeof(string), "=Fields.Name + ' ' + Fields.ProductNumber")); // Adding a sample calculated field.

    // Creating a new report
    Telerik.Reporting.Report report = new Telerik.Reporting.Report();

    // Assigning the ObjectDataSource component to the DataSource property of the report.
    report.DataSource = objectDataSource;

    // Use the InstanceReportSource to pass the report to the viewer for displaying
    Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource reportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();
    reportSource.ReportDocument = report;

    // Assigning the report to the report viewer.
    reportViewer1.ReportSource = reportSource;

    // Calling the RefreshReport method (only in WinForms applications).
    reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}

static DataSet GetAllData()
{
    const string connectionString =
        "Data Source=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True";

    string selectCommandText = "SELECT Name, ProductCategoryID FROM Production.ProductCategory;" +
        "SELECT Name, ProductCategoryID FROM Production.ProductSubcategory;" +
        "SELECT Name, ProductNumber FROM Production.Product;";

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommandText, connectionString);
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

    // The data set will be filled with three tables: ProductCategory, ProductSubcategory 
    // and Product as the select command contains three SELECT statements.
    adapter.Fill(dataSet);

    // Giving meaningful names for the tables so that we can use them later.
    dataSet.Tables[0].TableName = "ProductCategory";
    dataSet.Tables[1].TableName = "ProductSubcategory";
    dataSet.Tables[2].TableName = "Product";
    return dataSet;
}
```

Comment: i saw this example.   var objectDataSource = new Telerik.Reporting.ObjectDataSource() what is this statement mean

Comment: Generic C# ObjectDataSource class does not support assigning DataSet as DataSource. In this example author is using third party control as solution so this is not a valid answer.